# Find the particular solution of the differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$
dy/dx = {x\sqrt{y}\cos(x)},(0,9)
$$

This is what I have so far:
$$
2\sqrt{y} = x\sin(x)+\cos(x)
$$
I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: you finished the problem haha

Comment: @damier godfred Add an arbitrary constant and you're done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$dy/dx = {x\sqrt{y}\cos(x)},(0,9)$$
It's seperable
$$\int \frac {dy}{\sqrt y} = \int {x\cos(x)}dx$$
$$\int \frac {dy}{\sqrt y} = x\sin(x)-\int \sin(x)dx$$
$$ 2\sqrt y = x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+K$$

Since $y(0)=9$

$$K= 2\sqrt 9 -1 =6 -1=5$$
$$ 2\sqrt y = x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+5$$

Answer (score 1):

You will find

$$2\sqrt {y}=x\sin (x)+\cos (x)+C $$

and for $y=9$ and $x=0$,  it gives

$$6=1+C $$ then ...